# Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

делаю AJAX-валидацию формы на JQuery и скрипт на PHP.
Обработчик формы и запрос AJAX посылаю на файл signin.php, откуда должен возвращаться массив $response, однако выдает ошибку SyntaxError:Unexpected end of JSON input

Не знаю как исправить, нужно помощь, пожалуйста
Репозиторий со всем кодом тут: https://github.com/Annikangl/testovoe

**Файл script.js**

```js
$('.submitButton').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let email = $('input[name="email"]').val();
    let login = $('input[name="username"]').val();
    
    $.ajax({
        url: 'signin.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            email: email,
            login: login,
        },
        success: function(response) {
            
            if (response.status == 1) {
                document.location.href('users.php');
            }
            
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert(xhr.responseText + '|\n' + status + '|\n' +error);
        }
    });
});
```

Файл-обработчик формы: signin.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once "includes/config.php";
require_once "includes/Constants.php";
require_once "includes/Account.php";

$auth = new Account($con);

if (isset($_POST['submitButton'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];

    $singIn = $auth->login($email,$username);

    if ($singIn) {
      $response = array(
          'status' => true
      );
      json_encode($response);
      
  }
 }
?>
```

Сама форма:

```html
<?php
include "signin.php";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <title>Авторизация</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style/style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Авторизация -->
    
    <form>
    <h2>Авторизация</h2>
    <?= $auth->getError(Constants::$invalidData); ?>
    <label for="email">Введите email</label>
    <?php echo $auth->getError(Constants::$emailValidate); ?>
        <input type="email" name="email">

    <label for="name">Логин</label>
    <?php echo $auth->getError(Constants::$usernameValidate); ?>
        <input type="text" name="username">

        
        
        <button class="submitButton" type="submit" name="submitButton">Войти</button>
        <p>Нет аккаунта? <a href="register.php">Регистрация</a></p>
    </form>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Почему у вас при невыполнении условий в скрипте signin.php ответ не выдаётся со `status => false` ? Для теста в ajax поставьте `dataType: 'html'` и посмотрите что отдаёт вам сервер

Comment: Попробовал поставить dataType: 'html', блок success выполняется, но в ответ приходит пустота.

Comment: Когда я убираю AJAX и просто отправлю POST-запрос через форму, он попадает в нужный блок If($signIn) и выводит true когда нужно. Но как только я возвращаю AJAX - снова та же ошибка Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: Ну так почему пустота то? Почему не выводит `false`?

Comment: Я не знаю почему так происходит